# How many devices consuming 6.5W peak can I connect to a 100VA transformer?

Tags: power-supply, watts, power-consumption

Our customer wants to know the number of devices that they can connect to a transformer rated at 100VA. Our devices consume 6.5W peak when the batteries are charging. Here is my calculation and please let me know if I am wrong.

Formula to convert between Watt and VA.
S(VA) =  P(W) / PF
We have the P(W) value of our devices which is 6.5W at peak. For a DC circuit the PF= 1.
S(VA) = 6.5W/1 = 6.5VA

Divide 100VA to 6.5VA to get the number of devices that can be powered by the 100VA transformer.

Comment: So what is the result? Under 20?

Comment: you are forgetting to account for the power supply efficiency

Comment: Depends on device. Does all devices draw peak power at the same time? What will happen if there is not enough power?

Comment: Are you sure the AC to DC conversion has power factor of 1 and happens without other losses?

Answer (score 0):

> For a DC circuit the PF= 1.

If your device is supplied from DC then there's no point of talking about the power factor.

However...

Your customer wants to power a number of your circuit from a transformer, so they need an AC/DC converter. If their AC/DC converter is not PF-corrected (i.e. rectifier plus large bulky electrolytic capacitor) then the power factor will not be more than 0.6 meaning that your customer shouldn't expect more than 60W of **useful** power. This yields us that maximum 9 devices can be powered simultaneously. If their AC/DC converter is PF-corrected then, taking the efficiency of the converter (practically around 85-90%) into account, the number of devices can be as high as 13 i.e. 50% more compared to un-corrected converter.